# Will this sql structure crash my web server

Tags: sql, webserver

I currently have a hatchling plan with hostgator that I will be using to host the database end of my iOS messaging application. Each user has their own table to store all of their friends. If I have a few hundred people with accounts (this means a few hundred tables) will the web server be able to handle potentially thousands of requests per day to access these tables, or must I purchase a larger hosting plan?

Comment: I dont know your database structure, but why do you need a table for each user and their friends, wouldn't it be a better solution if you have a m:m recursive relationship to the user table himself? So you don't need a few hundred tables

Answer (score 1):

No idea wether or not it "crashes" your server or you need another hosting plan, but I can say one thing for sure: **that simply is a very very very bad idea**.

Create a table `User` and create a table `Friend` which basically contains two references to `User` entries/rows. Maybe add a timestamp or a state or whatever additional data you need.

Each user should be represented by one entry / row in the `User` table.
Each friendship should be represented by one entry / row in the `Friend` table.